# @KafkaListener function invoked but receiving empty list

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I'm executing locally a Producer and a Consumer using Spring Kafka. On the Producer events are published successfully to a topic, and the consumer assigned that topic not receive the content. The @KafkaListener function is invoked but the list received is empty. Looking the logs is possible note that when the Producer publish some event at the same time the Consumer receive events but with empty list The broker and structure is ok because other topics working.

**Consumer:**

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${topic}")
public void listener(final List<ConsumerRecord<String, GenericRecord>> events) {
    LOGGER.info("Received {} events",  events.size());
}

public Map<String, Object> listenerConfiguration() {
    HashMap<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();

    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaBootstrapServerUrl);
    props.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, schemaRegistryURL);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, kafkaGroupId);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, maxRecordsPerPoll.toString());
    return props;
}

public ConsumerFactory<String, GenericRecord> consumerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(listenerConfiguration());
}

@Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, GenericRecord> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
            final TransactionConsumerRetry transactionConsumerRetry) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, GenericRecord> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setBatchListener(Boolean.TRUE);
        factory.setAckDiscarded(true);
         return factory;
  }
```

output:

```
 2020-07-09 14:03:29,879 INFO  [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] class:Listener, Received 0 events
 2020-07-09 14:03:35,812 INFO  [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] class:Listener, Received 0 events
 2020-07-09 14:03:37,178 INFO  [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] class:Listener, Received 0 events
```

**Producer:**

```
   public void sendEvent(final String topic, final String key, final GenericRecord value)
            throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        try {
            kafkaTemplate.send(topic, key, value).get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String exceptionName = ExceptionUtils.getRootCause(e).getClass().getName();
            LOGGER.error("M=sendEvent, Msg=Error while sending event with ID: {}, Exception: {}", key, exceptionName);
            throw e;
        }
    }

   public ProducerFactory<String, GenericRecord> producerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(getProducerGenericRecordConfigurations());
    }

    private Map<String, Object> getProducerGenericRecordConfigurations() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaBootstrapServerUrl);
        configProps.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, schemaRegistryURL);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroSerializer.class);
        return configProps;
    }
```

I've checked servers, topics and configurations, whole is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are getting an empty list there (I didn't when I just tested it, I get a list of record values - type erasure), but for a batch listener (`List<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>>`) you must `setBatchListener(true)` on the container factory.

Comment: I don't see how it can possibly work without the framework being told that it's a batch listener. There must be something else going on that you are not showing; please post a small, complete, example that exhibits this behavior and I will take a look to see what's wrong.

Comment: I did a mistake. But the batchListener is true. Current behavior is the Listener function invoked content a empty list, and the producer publishing correctely. The schema, bootstrap url and else configurations are ok.

Comment: What you are describing makes no sense to me; I don't see any way the listener would get an empty list; I need to work with the project to figure out what's wrong, but it needs to be stripped down to the minimum first; and no Lombok, please.

Comment: I'm sorry for poor description. I'm working in that some time and not see reason to receive an empty list too, because of this I've published here. You can specify which information you need? Scenario: application was work fine, so I created another topic with the same configuration and I've configured to listen the new topic, and that behavior started. On the control-center I've checked that content is published successfully. Also, I edited on the Producer to the new topic, and not problems occurred.

Comment: I mean that I can't "guess" what it wrong; I just can't envision any possibility of the framework passing an empty list. That's why I need to see the full project (as minimal as possible - remove databases etc) so I can see what is wrong with the configuration.